# Fail to install Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to install Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate. I use the basic installation for “Getting Started” scenario. And select both “Team Foundation Server 2010” and “Build Service” component. However, after the installation, I see the following error message:

“Installation is completed. But there are errors in installing optional components”

“Fail to install the following components:”

“Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2(x64)”

I then check the error log, and find the following info:

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64): [2] WARNING! Setup Failed for optional component Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64). MSI returned error code 1603
`***EndOfSession***`

How to solve the problem?

Note on my computer, I have already installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you installing TFS 2010? It's ancient and no longer supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the “`Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2(x64)`” has been installed, just try to uninstaled it, then reinstall TFS again.

If the “`Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2(x64)`” not been installed, you can try to install the dependent application manually from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5783 and then retry the TFS installation.

Comment: Thank you. I just followed your advice, and then remove the "Build Service" component. Then TFS 2010 is installed successfully. Thank you very much.